# iOS Auto-Renewing Subscription Test Device Crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have an app that uses Auto-Renewing In-App Purchases... During testing, I was verifying receipts against Apple's test URL. Now all of my TestFlight testers, and myself, are having an issue now that the app is in the App Store. When I use my Apple ID and account in the app, the app crashes trying to verify the receipt.

I deleted my app account's receipt data on the server side, deleted the app, reinstalled, and signed out of my iTunes account and logged back in. So there shouldn't a receipt in the bundle or on the server side, but the crash still occurs. Other (non-test) users are not having the issue.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: Do you have a symbolicated crash log? Since it seems like your validation is happening on the server, have you instrumented/logged that to see if you're sending back bogus results?

Comment: I validate from the app, against Apple's server. No crash logs on my device when I check via Xcode.

Comment: What about the console log? Something should show up there too. How useful that info is may be up for debate once it's identified... There are definitely differences that need to be handled between production and sandbox validation.

Comment: After my testing (with Live app), it looks like the app thinks there is a receipt stored in `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]` and when it tries to verify that receipt (which was a sandbox purchase) against the live Apple verification URL, it crashes.

Comment: Sounds like you're not fully handling the case where you need to invoke a SKReceiptRefreshRequest (this part is referenced in the "Validating Receipts Locally" section of the Receipt Validation Programming Guide). https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2

Comment: BTW, you should either be validating locally or through a server. The hybrid you note is explicitly called out by Apple as a poor solution. "It is not possible to build a trusted connection between a user’s device and the App Store directly because you don’t control either end of that connection." (from the intro to "Validating Receipts With the App Store" in the Receipt Validation guide)

Comment: I do refresh the receipt, the app just thinks there's a receipt stored in: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]`... I thought deleting the app and signing out of my iTunes account would clear that data?

Comment: That's where the receipt should be now. Deleting the app deletes the receipt; in sandbox mode, you have to refresh the receipt on launch. Again, from the Receipt Validation Guide: "To retrieve the receipt data, use the appStoreReceiptURL method of NSBundle to locate the app’s receipt, and then read the entire file. If the appStoreReceiptURL method is not available, you can fall back to the value of a transaction's transactionReceipt property for backward compatibility. Then send this data to your server—as with all interactions with your server, the details are your responsibility."

Comment: @BradBrighton It looks like it's only errors for sandbox users... I'm getting a 21007 response from Apple, meaning the receipt is sandbox, trying to be verified against live server.... Any way to clear out the old sandbox receipts so test users can purchase from live version?

Comment: When you delete the app, the receipt goes away, to the best of my knowledge and personal experience. Assuming I'm correct, it means that some attribute of the installation makes Apple think this is a sandbox install, not a production one. Are your users still installing via TestFlight or from the App Store proper?

Comment: I thought the same thing... When I delete the app and re-install, same thing occurs, which is odd. I deleted, restarted and am installing fresh from the App Store, I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: The other "sanity check" would be to make a burner "real" Apple ID, log into the App Store with it, power cycle the device (I've seen general oddnesses in the past that imply cached credentials), and see if you encounter the same issue. If not, it's something related to the use of the Apple ID in TestFlight and will require Apple's help to resolve likely. If the problem persists even with the burner, Apple may still need to be involved, but the bizarro factor will be amped up.